# Camel case to Title case doesnt work for the first letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I need to make the given string to title case, no matter whether the input is lower or upper case

`memberships 1 - contactGroupMembership - contactGroupId`
*should return*
`Memberships 1 - Contact Group Membership - Contact Group Id`

`memberships1-contactGroupMembership-contactGroupId`
*should return*
`Memberships 1 - Contact Group Membership - Contact Group Id`

I have tried with

```
str.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1").replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g, " $1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this 2 step solution for your case:

```js
input = ['memberships 1 - contactGroupMembership - contactGroupId', 'memberships1-contactGroupMembership-contactGroupId'];

const re1 = /\B(?:[A-Z]|\d)|\b-\b|(?<=-)[a-z]/g;
const re2 = /\b[a-z]/g;

var repl = [];
input.forEach(str => {
  repl.push(str
    .replace(re1, ' $&')
    .replace(re2, m => m.toUpperCase())
  );
});

console.log(repl);
```

**Explanation:**

- In the first `.replace` we insert space at desired places using first regex:

  ```
  \B(?:[A-Z]|\d)|\b-\b|(?<=-)[a-z]
  ```

This matches a non-word boundary followed by upper case letter or digit or a `-` that is surrounded with word boundaries on both sides or a lower case letter that must be preceded with a `-`. [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/x3wABc/1)

- In the second step we match lower case letter after a word boundary and make it upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Very specific to this user case, but you can also use a replacer function to uppercase either the first character of a word or the first capital: `str.replace(/(\b[a-z])|([A-Z]+)/g, (m,p1,p2)=> (p1 ? '' : ' ') + (p1  || p2).toUpperCase());`

working: either beginning of the word (used in `p1`) or the first capital (`p2`) is found. The replacer function uppercases that match, and adds the extra space only if it is not a p1 match

Demo:

```js
let str = 'memberships 1 - contactGroupMembership - contactGroupId';

str = str.replace(/(\b[a-z])|([A-Z]+)/g, (m,p1,p2)=> (p1 ? '' : ' ') + (p1  || p2).toUpperCase());

console.log(str);
```